# using Microsoft graph API i want user profile photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Hi I am trying to get user photo, used

```
var tenantId = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("TenantId").Value;
               var clientId = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
             var clientSecret = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("clientSecret").Value;
               var InviteRedirectUrl = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("InviteRedirectUrl").Value;
               
                
               var Instance = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("Instance").Value;
               var URL = Instance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

               var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

               var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                      .Create(clientId)
                      .WithAuthority(URL)
                      .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                      .Build();


               GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                   new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                   {


                       var authResult = await confidentialClient
                       .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                       .ExecuteAsync();


                       requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                       new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                   })
                   );
Stream photo = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

I got following error

Code: BadRequest Message: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user. Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints. Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps. Inner error:

how to solve it?

Comment: Please share correlation id and timestamp of error message

Comment: Code: BadRequest
Message: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-08-21T15:39:12
 request-id: *********85-febb-***5-**bd-6*********37865413

Comment: Please let us know which flow your using?

Comment: using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

Comment: You cannot use /me with Client Credentials.
This is because /me is simply an alias for /user/{currentUser}. When you use Client Credentials, there isn't a "user" for the API to map this alias too.

Comment: What auth provider should i choose, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider

Comment: Please refer to this [msal authentication fow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) which helps to choose

Comment: i used interactive auth provider, but i get resource not found , As photo gets only in beta version

Comment: Can you please try this graph API in graph explorer and if you are facing any error  give us full error code without *

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?